# how to secure an azure web app using a palo alto networks ngf

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to secure an azure web app using a palo alto networks ngf. I wanted to place my web app in an App Service Environment but my boss wouldn't allow me to. Is there a way of achieving this without using an ASE?

Comment: please read this before posting; [ask], [mcve]. for example; what have you tried yourself first? add this to your question.

Comment: Perhaps, you can learn from [these videos](https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/resources/whitepapers/intelligent-architectures-azure-reference-architecture). It links the technical aspects of the Azure and Palo Alto Networks solution together before exploring the technical design models of the architecture.